# dh_python2 versioned dependencies from setup.py

Tags: python, version, setup.py, deb, install-requires

I am building a .deb package of python module with ***dpkg-buildpackage***.
in ***setup.py*** i have specified `install_requires=['othermodule>=2.0']`
but the generated ***control*** file does not specify version. `Depends: python (>= 2.7), othermodule,`
dh_python is guessing the requirements based on setup.py file. However the manpage of [dh_python2](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/python/dh_python2.1.en.html) states that

> (version requirements are ignored by default)

but I cannot manage to include the version in the control file. 
The problem is that without the version included the .deb package gets installed but then starting the program I get:

`pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'othermodule>=2.0' distribution was not found and is required by ...`

because the version installed is less than 2.0

I would like to be able to specify the dependency version only once (in the setup.py for example)

[EDIT:]

I see that in pydist.py the function load() searches in absolute paths:

```
def load(dname='/usr/share/python/dist/', fname='debian/pydist-overrides',
         fbname='/usr/share/python/dist_fallback'):
```

instead of under ./debian where my package structure lays. And since the package is not installed yet (I am in the process of building it) the pydist file is not found. Am I missing something???

Comment: tried to use pydist file in the debian folder with:
`OthermoduleName python-othermodule; PEP386`
but no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Pybuild wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Pybuild):

> dh_python2 and dh_python3 will correctly fill in the installation dependencies (via ${python:Depends} and ${python3:Depends} respectively)

So, if you will use `${python:Depends}` in your debian/control, dh_python will try to map your `install_requires` from `setup.py` to actual deb dependencies. Use it like this:

```
Depends: python (>= 2.7), ${misc:Depends}, ${python:Depends}
```

You can also specify the desired version for your `othermodule` in debian/control just like you did for python:

```
Depends: python (>= 2.7), othermodule (>=2.0)
```

[**EDIT**]

You can place a `pydist-overrides` file under the debian folder that makes use of `PEP386` to force dh_python to include version information when resolving install dependencies. It uses the same syntax as a .pydist file:

```
OthermoduleName python-othermodule; PEP386
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I have exactly that line: `Depends: python (>= 2.7), ${misc:Depends}, ${python:Depends}`  but the problem is that it does not translate the version from the _install_requires_. I can specify explicitly in the _control_ file but would like to specify requirements only one (in one of the files)

Comment: It seems like having _PEP386_ flag in a pydist file is the only way I find to make dh_python2 translate dependency versions. The issue is as I mention in my question that it look for that file in the python installation path instead of the source tree where I am building the package and running dh_python from

Comment: Have you tried using a `pydist-overrides` file instead of a `python-foo.pydist` file?
It uses the same syntax as the pydist file: `OthermoduleName python-othermodule; PEP386`

Comment: There you go! it worked like a charm :) man, I spent so much time tweaking this. Bless your heart! Can I convert your comment as an answer?

Comment: I will edit the current answer to include this information so you can mark it as accepted answer. Is this ok?